# Split data based on break value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am struggling to split the into 2 rows instead of more rows for id on particular day.

The data looks like as

```
Id    Date        status   starttime             endtime
1   15/08/2021     work1   15/08/2021 09:00:00   15/08/2021 09:20:00
1   15/08/2021     work2   15/08/2021 09:20:00   15/08/2021 10:20:00
1   15/08/2021     Break   15/08/2021 10:20:00   15/08/2021 10:50:00
1   15/08/2021     work3   15/08/2021 10:50:00   15/08/2021 12:00:00
1   15/08/2021     work4   15/08/2021 12:00:00   15/08/2021 14:00:00
```

Now my expected output would be

```
Id    Date        status   starttime             endtime
1   15/08/2021     BB      15/08/2021 09:00:00   15/08/2021 10:20:00
1   15/08/2021     Break   15/08/2021 10:20:00   15/08/2021 10:50:00
1   15/08/2021     AB      15/08/2021 10:50:00   15/08/2021 14:00:00
```

I need to split data before break and after break.
Can someone help me to break this record.

Comment: Thanks Dale for your reply. I don't have any clue how to minimize this data. I am new to sql.

Comment: In that case it seems you're jumping to too hard a problem. You should start with something simple, learn the basics and work up to advanced queries. Otherwise someone is just doing all the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

**We can use a running `COUNT` to calculate whether `Break` has passed yet.**

We can then calculate the new status using `CASE`, place that inside an apply, then group by that.

```sql
SELECT
  t.Id,
  t.Date,
  v.Status,
  startime = MIN(t.starttime),
  endtime =  MAX(t.endtime)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      CountBreak = COUNT(CASE WHEN t.status = 'Break' THEN 1 END)
              OVER (PARTITION BY Id, Date ORDER BY t.starttime ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM YourTable t
) t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
  CASE WHEN t.CountBreak = 0 AND t.status <> 'Break' THEN 'BB'
       WHEN t.status = 'Break' THEN 'Break'
       ELSE 'AB' END
) ) v(Status)
GROUP BY
  t.Id,
  t.Date,
  v.Status;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9fa28/1)

Comment: You becoming the free coding service we say we don't offer? :)

Comment: To be brutally honest, if I think a question won't get closed quick enough, or at all, and it's easy enough, then I'll just bash out an answer, rather than risk all manner of garbage being posted as answers. It might be FGITW, but at least it's correct, performant, and demonstrates good coding practice.

Comment: Lack of attempt isn't really a close reason anyway unfortunately...